# A problem on finding some covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Describe three pairwise non-homemorphic two-fold coverings of $RP^{2}\vee S^{1}$.  $RP^{2}$ is the real projective plane and $\vee$ represents the wedge product of topological spaces.

I know that map $S^{2}\rightarrow RP^{2}$ is a two-fold covering. So the space $S^{2} \vee S^{1} \times S^{1}$ is one desired space.But I have some difficult to find the other two.

Comment: Hint/suggestion: Do you know any two-sheeted coverings of the circle?

Answer (score 3):

here they are:

[image]

the second and third are homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1\vee S^1$, but are not homeomorphic to.

these three coverings correspond to three different subgrups of $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2\vee S^1)=\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z_2$ of index $2$. denote the generators of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ by $a$ and $b$. then these subgroups are the normal closures of 
$\langle a^2,b \rangle$
$\langle a, bab \rangle$ and
$\langle ab \rangle$.

Comment: I've read your proof for several days and find as many relative theorems as possible to understand your proof.But I still don't understand it.Can you specify your answer a little bit.I'm really grateful and I'm sorry for my silliness. For example,can you give me some hints about how to prove the figures you pictured are the covering space in strict way and how to calculate the fundamental group of these spaces ?